# nodejs sql connection app crash

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following nodejs app which connects to SQL db. As soon as when   call API, it get success but app crashes. I am new to nodejs to understand the issue exactly.

I executed this post call from rest client tool. It gives success but app crashes after that. https://localhost:8089/updateUserBalance with required parameter.

```
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    port: '3306',
    user: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    password: '394e1836',
    database: 'ad_fd0a197d2dcabf7'
  });

var port = 8089;//(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000);
var host = 'localhost';//(process.env.VCAP_APP_HOST || 'localhost');
app.set('port', port);
app.use(express.logger());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// parse the raw data
app.use(bodyParser.raw());
// parse text
app.use(bodyParser.text());
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
//var jsonParser = bodyParser.raw();
var productsRouter=express.Router();app.use(app.router);


// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}
function handle_database(req,res) {

     pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
         if (err) {
           connection.release();
           res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
           return;
         }   
         console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);

         connection.on('error', function(err) {      
               res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
               return;     
         });
   });
 }


app.post('/updateUserBalance',function(req, res, next){

   setSafeUpdate();
   //ToDo update timestamp also
   var sql = "update USERDETAILS set balance ='"+req.body.balance+"'where username ='"+req.body.username+"';";
   var query = db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
     if (err) {
       console.error(err);
       return res.send(err);
     } else {
       return res.send('Ok');
     }
});
});
app.post('/getUserDetails', function(req, res, next){

var sql = "select * from USERDETAILS where username ='"+req.body.username+"'order by timestamp limit 1;";
console.log(sql);
   var query = db.query(sql,function(err, result) {
     if (err) {
       console.error(err);
       return res.send(err);
     } else {
       res.json({ "Message" : "Success", "Record" : result});
     }
});
});


// start server
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening at http://' + host + ':' + port);
});
```

Here is the crash log

```
C:\\app>node app.js
    Express server listening at http://localhost:8089
    safeupdate : [object Object]
    ::1 - - [Thu, 15 Dec 2016 08:33:55 GMT] "POST /updateUserBalance HTTP/1.1" 200
     "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko
     Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36"
    events.js:160
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (C:\bluemix-node-mysql-uploader-master\app\node_modules\mys
l\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:109:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\bluemix-node-mysql-uploader-master\app\node_modul
s\mysql\lib\Connection.js:115:28)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Comment: post your message so it will easy to track

Comment: @bhaskar, you code seem to work well for me except `setSafeUpdate();`. Can you post the body of that function?

Comment: Thanks for the response sridhar.pls check the code you asked.It is always crashes for me :-)
function setSafeUpdate()
{
 var sql = 'SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0';
 db.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
              console.log("safeupdate : "+result);
  });
 
}